# A simple & clear explanation of the Gini impurity?

Tags: cart, intuition, gini

In a context of decision tree splitting, it is not obvious to see why the **Gini impurity**
$$
i(t)=1-\sum\limits_{j=1}^k p^2(j|t)
$$
is a measure of **node t impurity**. Is there an easy explanation of this?

Comment: This answer on a related question may help you better understand the intuition: https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/339514/27974

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Imagine an experiment with $k$ possible output categories. Category $j$ has a probability of occurrence $p(j|t)$ (where $j=1,..k$)

Reproduce the experiment two times and make these observations:

- the probability of obtaining **two identical outputs of category $j$** is $$ p^2(j|t) $$
- the probability of obtaining **two identical outputs, independently of their category**, is: $$\sum\limits_{j=1}^k p^2(j|t)$$
- the probability of obtaining **two different outputs** is thus: $$1-\sum\limits_{j=1}^k p^2(j|t)$$

That's it: the Gini impurity is simply the probability of obtaining two different outputs, which is an "impurity measure".

---

**Remark:** another expression of the Gini index is:
$$
\sum\limits_{j=1}^k p_j(1-p_j)
$$
This is the same quantity:
$$
\sum\limits_{j=1}^k p_j(1-p_j) = \left(\sum\limits_{j=1}^k p_j \right) -\left( \sum\limits_{j=1}^k p^2_j \right) = 1 - \sum\limits_{j=1}^k p^2_j 
$$

Comment: Same math but with a more practical interpretation: it is natural to predict the class $j = 1 \ldots k$ of an element in the set by selecting a class $j$ with probability $p(j)$. 1-Gini then simply gives you the (Rand) accuracy. Thus, a Gini impurity of 0 means a 100 % accuracy in predicting the class of the elements, so they are all of the same class. Similarly, a Gini impurity of 0.5 means a 50 % chance of correctly classifying an element of the set with this natural method, etc.

Comment: I think the usage of "outputs" above is a little confusing - the "output" actually means the true class or category, and has nothing to do with the output of the decision tree classifier.

Comment: On another note, I believe "reproduce the experience..." should read "reproduce the experiment...". (I tried to edit, but the edit was rejected - https://stats.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/268539.)

Comment: @PicaudVincent No worries - I found this answer to be very helpful and I just thought I'd add the comments, in hopes it will make it even more useful to other readers. Enjoy your vacation!

Answer (score -1):

Gini impurity = logical entropy = Gini-Simpson biodiversity index = quadratic entropy with logical distance function (1-Kroneckerdelta), etc.
See: Ellerman, David. 2018. “Logical Entropy: Introduction to Classical and Quantum Logical Information Theory.” Entropy 20 (9): Article ID 679. https://doi.org/10.3390/e20090679, and the references contained therein.

Comment: Economists are apt to call this the Herfindahl-Hirschman index.